# Not in List Operation - AeroSpike

Tags: aerospike

Does AeroSpike support not in operation on List ? I couldn't see it in the document or find any reference to it. Could somebody confirm if that's the case ?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. Aerospike does not support "not in" operation on list. It will be an operation based on a search value, if my understanding is correct. There are no list read operations by value.